# navigation to new page doesnot scroll top

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

There are few links on a page, when the user clicks on a link it should redirect to the new page, As of now it is redirecting to the new page but the issue is that the new page doesnot scroll to top and it stays at the same location where the user clicked the link on the old page. The new page scrolls to top only when the page is refreshed. How to solve this issue?

Comment: are you using Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

if you using `ng-view` to show your navigate page then can try using `autoscroll="true"`

```
<div ng-view="" autoscroll="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to one of the top elements of the page. For example:

```
<div id="mytopdiv"></div>
```

And then you can add "#mytopdiv" to the end of the url for redirecting. For example: "http://www.mypage.com#mytopdiv"